# How to override _score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents indexed as below

```
{
   "article": "...",
   "tags": [{ name: '...', values: [{ value: 'a' }, { value: 'b' }]
}
```

I'm looking for some documents by tags, so i have parent - nested (tags) - nested (values) structure and in value I've prepared my `script_fields` which includes score for each tag found.

For now, results from query:

```
[
  {
    ...
    "_score": 1.1308107,
    "_source": {
        ...
    },
    "inner_hits": {
      "...": {
        "hits": {
          "total": 2,
          "max_score": 1.7890062,
          "hits": [
            {
             ...
              "_score": 1.7890062,
              "fields": {
                "myScore": [
                  15.45
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and question is

Is it possible to replace global `_score` value to `inner_hits[...].hits.hits[0].fields.myScore[0]`? (In this example replace `1.1308107` with `15.45`) or exclude those documents which have `inner_hits[...].hits.hits[0].fields.myScore[0]`? smaller than 20?

Comment: Can you explain a use case?

Comment: I would like to exclude those documents which have `inner_hits[...].hits.hits[0].fields.myScore[0]` smaller than 20 - it is my use case :)

Comment: Good but can you tell what is you use case, maybe its possible to do in other way?

Comment: I would like to use my scoring system to predict article by tags, but tags are stored as an entries in article object

Comment: So basically what you want to do is to find documents by tags ?

Comment: Also please add you query you have so far

Comment: I would like only to sort my query result by my scory function like in this [example](http://pastebin.com/meeWW7mZ).

Looks that the documents are sorted in descending order by myScore

Comment: There is https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Comment: Also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Comment: But i still dont understand what you want to do

Comment: In other words: In query in nested I have my own function score which calculate score for every tag, and the results for query looks [like](http://pastebin.com/meeWW7mZ)

and now i would like to sort this results by **myScore** from **inner_hits**

Comment: Please post your query pls.

Comment: Ok, it is [example](http://pastebin.com/wG2uXNAP)